# Integrating Cognito with API key authentication based API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have built an API that works with API keys which I generate and distribute to users. Now, after some time I added Cognito registration and created a user portal for the users of the API. I also added a Lambda post-registration after Cognito registration callback that adds a user into my database when someone registers and then it generates an API key automatically.

For the user portal I created: Would it be reasonable to only authenticate once using the JWT authentication and once that's done to automatically match it to the API key from that and then just serve the user the appropriate API key and all further requests would be with the API key (store the JWT token in local storage and exchange on first entry point)? That way I don't need to take into account multiple ways of authentication for each API endpoint.

My API is running on a EC2 machine with a nginx server.

I tried implementing it and it works but I'm just wondering if it is secure to do it this way.